# Insufficient Privileges to access a Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, administration, profile, insufficient-privileges, access

How to know what is missing for a user to view a custom object (example custom object "**Book**")

I am getting **Isufficient Privileges** when I login as a user with a "XXX - Agent" Profile

When I check the profile it has :

*Custom Object Permissions*   Book : **Read** Access checked

*Custom tab settings*  Book : **Default On**

[image]

Comment: you do not have access to record. OWD settings for book object is private.

Comment: Why not post that as an answer, @ShravanBoddula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ShravanBoddula

The book object was set to private in the OWD

To resolve this

Goto *Setup -> Security controls -> Sharing Settings*  and set the Object to at least *Public Read Only*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query to the Share object of your `Custom object` (Every `Custom Object` has its `Share Object` in the form: `CustomObject__Share`, you can consult it in [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm)). The query should look to something like this :

```
SELECT AccessLevel, ParentId, RowCause, UserOrGroupId FROM <YourCustomObject__Share> where UserOrGroupId = <YourUserId> and ParentId = <YourRecordId>
```

And you can also query for an object called : UserRecordAccess, you can see available fields [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm)